# How to properly backup snap settings

Tags: backup, snap

Usually when doing backups we zip the home folder and call it a day.

Looking into the `~/snap` directory there are sub-directories with numbers which leads me to believe that backing those up would not work just like that.

Is zipping the home folder enough to back up snap packages' settings?

Answer (score 2):

All snap settings are in the `~/snap` directory. I think numbers corresponds to the version ID of a snap package.

Comment: Does that mean in the case where say I updated a snap and then restored a backup of the configuration files from the previous version then my settings wouldn't be applied

Answer (score 2):

A backup of your entire home folder including hidden files will equally well backup your current configuration data for the snaps under the ~/snap folder. So yes, zipping is enough to back up all snap packages' personal settings.

Answer (score 0):

Backing up home directory does not mean backing up your system (your applications), your home only contains configurations and cache in `.config` & `.cache` respectively. if you really want to backup applications you need to get the archives from `/var/cache/apt/archives` or in `/snap/'.

A simple solution is to backup using a graphical tool if you are new to Linux and i would suggest `Timeshift` as a started and DO NOT FORGET TO ADD YOUR HOME DIRECTORY BECAUSE IT IS EXECLUDED BY DEFAULT!.

If you are using linux for a while and you are running low on memory (do not want to store your entire system); then just backup those
1-Your ppa; found in `/etc/apt/sources.list` & `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`
2-Environmental path; found in `/etc/environment`
3-apt packages; through `apt list --installed`
4-snap apps; through `snap list`
5-home directory

The second method will not require more than 1MB as if you created a backup from each; you will just need to restore the backup file. Take this example, `apt list --installed > apt_backup